# Extend FormDigestSettings.Timeout -> Performance impact?

Tags: form, administration, performance

we have item forms where people need a long time to fill out.
I many cases the form digest timout is reached and the item not saved.

SharePoint writes the log error message

> ViewStateLog: Failed to find entry in cache:
>   https://sharepoint/sites/Site1/List1/NewForm.aspx

A solution on [this site](http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/08/sharepoint-30-minute-time-out-for-forms.html) is to extend the form digest timeout.
The question I have is:

- Is extending the timeout a recommended way?
- What is the performance and storage impact when setting the timout to 8 hours
- Are there other recommended ways to extend my viewstate session? (calling *document.form[0].submit()* would work, but SharePoint clears the RichText-Fields)

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is depend upon the requirement, as per my experience we increase this timing to 2 hours on one web application out of many.

> The Web Page Security Validation feature helps enhance security by
>   imposing a time limit on Web pages when a user submits information to
>   the server. When a user tries to submit information to the server
>   after the validation time-out expires, the user receives the error
>   message that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section. If users
>   frequently experience the symptoms that are described in the
>   "Symptoms" section, consider increasing the security validation
>   time-out value.

Increase it to 8 hours, for me clearly a big security gap. You are giving a user 8 hours to keep the data and using the Memory for long time. Definitely a performance issue.